# Como redireccionar al login cuando caduca la sesión en laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel

Buenas noches amigos necesito saber como redireccionar al login cuando caduca la sesión en laravel 5.2 ya que hay momentos que dejan la sesión abierta por mas de 3 horas y al momento que desean utilizar llenan todos los datos de la factura pero al momento de guardar les da un error y es que la variable SESIÓN id_sucursal es NULL 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Claro esta que si vuelven a iniciar sesión ya no les da este error yo estoy poniendo en tiempo de duración de la sesión en config/session.php y esta de esta manera
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

por favor di alguien me podría ayudar con esto

Answer (score 0):

Si esa vista (la de rellenar la factura), necesita que sea un usuario logueado. Lo lógico es que se proteja esa ruta con un Middleware en el archivo de routes.php.
De esta manera, se asegura que esa vista solo sea renderizada con un usuario logueado. Si la sesión caduca, será redireccionado a la página de login sin causar ese error que tiene ahora.

La documentación oficial de Middleware para la versión 5.2 de Laravel, aquí:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/middleware

Ejemplo para el caso de la vista 'admin/profile':

```
    Route::get('admin/profile', ['middleware' => 'auth', function () {
    //
    }]);
```